# jackson json deserializer with subnode list of elements

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a deserializer for `MyObject` that extends the `StdDeserializer<MyObject>`. In its `deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)` I would like to convert a subnode of the node I am deserializing into a list of pojos. Given json like

```
{
  "property1" : "value1",
  ...
  "subnode" : [
    {
      "snProperty1" : "value1",
      "snProperty2" : "value2",
      ...
      "snPropertyN" : "valueN"
    },
    { ... }, // other elements like the one above
    { ... }
 ],
  ...
}
```

and pojos

```
class Subnode {
    private String snProperty1;
    private String snProperty2;
    ...
    private Stirng snPropertyN;
    // getters and setters
}

class MyObject {
    private String property1;
    ...
    private List<Subnode> subnodes;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I want the deserializer to handle all the `Subnode` objects without iterating and using `Subnode` setters myself. Something similar to `TypeReference`s and an `ObjectMapper`.

Is the only way to instantiate an `ObjectMapper` to do the above? Like for example

```
objectMapper.convertValue(subnode, new TypeReference<List<Subnode>>() {});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it without the use of an `ObjectMapper` by using the parser (`p`) codec.

```
List<Subnode> subnodes = new ArrayList<>();
if (myObject.hasNonNull("subnodeList")) {
    ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
    for (JsonNode subnode : myObject.get("subnodeList")) {
        subnodes.add(codec.treeToValue(subnode, Subnode.class));
    }
}
myObject.setSubnodes(subnodes);
```